# ThreadLocal property

Tags: c#, properties, thread-local

If we have a `ThreadLocal` property (each thread has it's unique property) then which one is correct (we don't want use automatic setter/getter):

**A)**

```
private ThreadLocal<MyClass> _someProperty = new ThreadLocal<MyClass>();

public ThreadLocal<MyClass> SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _someProperty.Value;
    }
    set
    {
        _someProperty.Value = value;
    }
}
```

**B)**

```
private ThreadLocal<MyClass> _someProperty = new ThreadLocal<MyClass>();

public MyClass SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _someProperty.Value;
    }
    set
    {
        _someProperty.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to *encapsulate* the `ThreadLocal<T>`, so that the caller only needs to know about `MyClass`; in which case, you still need to access `.Value` explicitly, as that is where the per-thread magic happens:

```
private readonly ThreadLocal<MyClass> _someProperty = new ThreadLocal<MyClass>();

public MyClass SomeProperty
{
    get { return _someProperty.Value; }
    set { _someProperty.Value = value; }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get at the 'ThreadLocal<T>' value without a reference to the _someProperty member? Say the only information you had was the thread itself ( in the same way that you can use `Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("myDataName")` to get data from a thread).

Comment: I assume this will also work if I'm calling the property LOCALLY from within MyClass?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the second form, to ensure that you control when the value is set.

If you expose the `ThreadLocal` directly, your caller can write `SomeProperty.Value = null`, and you won't be able to prevent it.

By forcing all access to go through your class, you can add validation to the setter.

Also, the first form allows one thread to erase the property's values on other threads by replacing the entire `ThreadLocal` instance.

Note that your code won't compile; you need to return and set `.Value`.